# cannot initialize type with a collection initializer

Tags: c#

I have a class Options.

```
public class Option
{                
    public bool Aggregation { get; set; }
    public PropertyOptions Property { get; set; }
    public bool DoEvent { get; set; }
}
```

PropertyOptions goes like this..

```
public enum PropertyOptions
{        
    [EnumMember]
    On = 0,     
    [EnumMember]
    Off = 1,
    [EnumMember]        
    Auto = 2,
}
```

Now I have a method which return an object of a class Option

```
Option setOptions()
{
        return new Option()
        {
            Aggregation = true,                
            Property = new PropertyOptions()
            {
                PropertyOptions.Auto,
            },                                       
            DoEvent = true,
       };
}
```

Here I am getting an error which says "Cannot initialize type PropertyOptions with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collection.IEnumerable"

I am not sure about how to set data member 'Property'.
It would be helpful if someone can drove my attention to what could be the possible error and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use regular assignment.

```
new Option()
{
    Aggregation = true,                
    Property = PropertyOptions.Auto,                                   
    DoEvent = true
}
```

The syntax you were attempting to use is for collection initialization. For example:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "apple",
    "banana"
};
```

Your `Property` property is not a collection.

Answer (score 3):

The New Operator is for instantiating objects from Classes. You are using an Enum, which is not a Class.

You should be able to just use an assignment operator.

```
new Option()
{
    Aggregation = true,                
    Property = PropertyOptions.Auto,                                   
    DoEvent = true
};
```